# Показ картинки при наводе мышкой

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, нашел такой код, он показывает картинки при наведении.

```
    <a class="text-hover-image" href="#">very special hover</a>
<span class="text-hover-image"><em>"text-hover-image"</em></span>

    span {
}

    $(document).ready(function () {
    var yOff = 15;
    var xOff = -20;
    var pathToImage = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png";

    $(".text-hover-image").hover(function (e) {
        $("body").append("<p id='image-when-hovering-text'><img src='" + pathToImage + "'/></p>");
        $("#image-when-hovering-text")
            .css("position", "absolute")
            .css("height", "10px")
            .css("width", "10px")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");

    },

    function () {
        $("#image-when-hovering-text").remove();
    });

    $(".text-hover-image").mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#image-when-hovering-text")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/55yxf/1/
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить размер картинки, а то что-то я стиль меняю, а картинка остается прежней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в css добавить стиль:

```
#image-when-hovering-text img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/55yxf/22/)

Comment: спасибо, а то я пробывал а нефига. Видимо брал не тот ID